How to duplicate same row X number of times based on the value of a column?
I have a dataset looks like this:



Link_number
Houband
Time
Mean_speed
Sample_Number




Link 1
8
8:00
52
2


Link 1
8
8:30
55
5


Link 2
9
9:00
20
3


Link 2
9
9:30
40
4



I need to do duplicate each row X number of times, X = Sample_Number. So my result will look like this:



Link_number
Houband
Time
Mean_speed
Sample_Number




Link 1
8
8:00
52
2


Link 1
8
8:00
52
2


Link 1
8
8:30
55
5


Link 1
8
8:30
55
5


Link 1
8
8:30
55
5


Link 1
8
8:30
55
5


Link 1
8
8:30
55
5


Link 2
9
9:00
20
3


Link 2
9
9:00
20
3


Link 2
9
9:00
20
3


Link 2
9
9:30
40
4


Link 2
9
9:30
40
4


Link 2
9
9:30
40
4


Link 2
9
9:30
40
4



So then I can calculate the percentile of speed in each hourband for each link.
I have been able to do this in Postgresql using generate_series:
select Link_number, Hourband, percentile_cont(0.85) within group (order by Mean_Speed) as Speed_85th
from table, generate_series(1,Sample_Number)


How do I do the same in Amazon Athena?

Please include sample data directly in the question; do not use external links.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

You can use a tally table.

You can use unnest + sequence (which is kind of analog of generate_series based on what I see):
-- sample data
WITH dataset(Link_number, Houband, Time, Mean_speed, Sample_Number) as (
    values ('Link 1',   8,  '8:00', 52, 2),
        ('Link 1',  8,  '8:30', 55, 5),
        ('Link 2',  9,  '9:00', 20, 3),
        ('Link 2',  9,  '9:30', 40, 4)
)

-- query
select Link_number, Houband, Time, Mean_speed, Sample_Number
from dataset,
     unnest(sequence(1, Sample_Number)) as t(ignored);


@ritarita was glad to help! Feel free to upvote useful answers too)

As @Serg recommended, you can use a tally table to generate a sequence of numbers then use a cross join to duplicate the rows based on these values.
WITH numbers AS (
    SELECT n
    FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)) AS t(n)
)

SELECT 
    Link_number,
    Houband,
    Time,
    Mean_speed,
    Sample_Number
FROM 
    your_table AS t
JOIN 
    numbers AS n
ON 
    n.n <= t.Sample_Number


Arguably unnest + sequnece (please see my answer) is better approach here.
